# Request file via new url or other url with proxy

Tags: url, proxy

hey here is the problem

Like i have this image images/movies/Homefront_2013.jpg

But i want this image from the proxy server like proxy/Homefront_2013.jpg

from httym because this site dont work in my country

image is example i need to view videos too
i am trying to view youtube vivo videos

**I have tried glype proxy but it don't work for videos**

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. Would you mind clarifying a bit? What server are you trying to access via proxy?

Comment: i am trying to view youtube vivo videos

Comment: If you're only trying to view them, then you need to find a proxy server to use, and configure your browser or network connection to use it. I don't know what kind of system you have using, or what browser you are using, so here is an addon for firefox to manage proxies: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/

Answer (score 0):

You can just buy a VPN for that (http://www.hidemyass.com/vpn/), or try to use public proxy (http://www.liste-proxy.fr).